# Property 'getSubcommand' does not exist on type 'Omit<CommandInteractionOptionResolver<CacheType>'

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I'm trying to use `interaction.options.getSubcommand()`. However I'm getting this error:

```
Property 'getSubcommand' does not exist on type 'Omit<CommandInteractionOptionResolver<CacheType>, "getMessage" | "getFocused" | "getMentionable" | "getRole" | "getAttachment" | ... 6 more ... | "getSubcommand">'.
```

This is my Hello.ts file:

```ts
import {
  CommandInteraction,
  CommandInteractionOptionResolver,
  SlashCommandBuilder,
} from "discord.js";
import { CustomClient } from "../Client";
import { Command } from "../Command";

export default class HelloCommand extends Command {
  public constructor(client: CustomClient) {
    super(client, {
      name: "hello",
      description: "Says hello to user.",
    });
  }

  public getOptions() {
    return new SlashCommandBuilder()
      .setName(this.name)
      .setDescription(this.description)
      .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
        subcommand.setName("say").setDescription("Say hello to someone.")
      ) as SlashCommandBuilder;
  }

  public async execute(interaction: CommandInteraction): Promise<void> {
    const subcommand = interaction.options.getSubcommand();
    if (subcommand === "say") {
      interaction.reply({ content: `Hello, ${interaction.user.username}` });
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Command.ts file:

```ts
import { CommandInteraction, PermissionResolvable } from "discord.js";
import { CustomClient } from "./Client";
import { SlashCommandBuilder } from "@discordjs/builders";

interface CommandOptions {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  permission?: PermissionResolvable;
}

export abstract class Command {
  public client: CustomClient;
  public name: string;
  public description: string;
  public permission?: PermissionResolvable;

  constructor(client: CustomClient, props: CommandOptions) {
    this.client = client;
    this.name = props.name;
    this.description = props.description;
    this.permission = props.permission;
  }

  abstract getOptions(): SlashCommandBuilder;

  abstract execute(interaction: CommandInteraction): any;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the problem about my Command.ts code?

Comment: Can you share your type definition of `CommandInteractionOptionResolver` as well?

Comment: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/packages/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts#L1177

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class `HelloCommand` you define a function `execute` with a parameter `interaction` of type `CommandInteraction`. In this type there is a property defined called `options`.

Lets have a closer look to the type definition of options:
https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/packages/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts#L541

```
export abstract class CommandInteraction<Cached extends CacheType = CacheType> extends BaseInteraction<Cached> {
  public options: Omit<
    CommandInteractionOptionResolver<Cached>,
    | 'getMessage'
    | 'getFocused'
    | 'getMentionable'
    | 'getRole'
    | 'getUser'
    | 'getMember'
    | 'getAttachment'
    | 'getNumber'
    | 'getInteger'
    | 'getString'
    | 'getChannel'
    | 'getBoolean'
    | 'getSubcommandGroup'
    | 'getSubcommand'
  >;
...
}
```

The `options` property uses the type `CommandInteractionOptionResolver` in combination with the `Omit` utility type of Typescript.
This means that the type of `options` is the type `CommandInteractionOptionResolver` without all the keys of the union type, which are defined as second argument in `Omit`.
So in your case you cannot call `interaction.options.getSubcommand()`, because the property `options` does not have a function `getSubcommand` defined.

Hint:
There is one other type `ChatInputCommandInteraction`, which extends the type `CommandInteraction`. Have a look at this type maybe it fits for you, because the `options` property of this type still has the function `getSubcommand`.
https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/packages/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts#L1149

If you decide to use the type `ChatInputCommandInteraction` for your `HelloCommand` class than you can just use `ChatInputCommandInteraction` as the type of `interaction` instead of changing the abstract function definition in your abstract class `Command`.

```
export default class HelloCommand extends Command {

...

  // change the interaction type from CommandInteraction to ChatInputCommandInteraction
  public async execute(interaction: ChatInputCommandInteraction): Promise<void> {
    const subcommand = interaction.options.getSubcommand();
    if (subcommand === "say") {
      interaction.reply({ content: `Hello, ${interaction.user.username}` });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It solved my problem. All I had to do was use `ChatInputCommandInteraction` instead of `CommandInteraction`. Thanks for the clear explanation.